# How to search from Excel file in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: excel, search, sharepoint-2013

Can I create form in SharePoint 2013 to search from Excel content?

The excel file uploaded to Site Assets. 
The user can search from any column, I mean the user choice the column by radio buttons.

Thanks
BR.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the use of a excel sercvices in a SP 2013.

You can use the REST api for the excel service and then write a code for the serach in the columns as per the user selections.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76528/search-excel-spreadsheet-or-microsoft-access-within-sharepoint

Thanks

Comment: Thanks :) I will try

Comment: Hi sameer,are you able to achieve whatever you want ? Please accept the answer if it helped you, so that other users can take a benefit of it